# twitter4j twitterobjectfactory.createstatus returns retweetedStatus as null

Tags: java, json, twitter4j

I have been storing a considerable amount of Tweets in JSon format. Now that I'm attempting to read them back into Status, the object creation only fills in some of the fields, even though the raw Json contains all of the information.

Here is the raw JSON

```
{"createdAt":"Aug 5, 2014 4:03:39 PM",
"id":496733290263760896,
"text":"RT @lucasfresno: Bora se encacha?ar! RT @zerohora: Leia agora em http://t.co/ho1jjRsIpH http://t.co/VPRDdg35oO",
"source":"\u003ca href\u003d\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel\u003d\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c/a\u003e",
"isTruncated":false,
"inReplyToStatusId":-1,
"inReplyToUserId":-1,
"isFavorited":false,
"retweetCount":0,
"isPossiblySensitive":false,
"contributorsIDs":[],
"retweetedStatus":{"createdAt":"Aug 5, 2014 1:39:46 PM",
                   "id":496697079394492417,
                   "text":"Bora se encacha?ar! RT @zerohora: Leia agora em http://t.co/ho1jjRsIpH http://t.co/VPRDdg35oO",
                   "source":"\u003ca href\u003d\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel\u003d\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c/a\u003e",
                   "isTruncated":false,
                   "inReplyToStatusId":496694316656381952,
                   "inReplyToUserId":13531162,
                   "isFavorited":false,
                   "inReplyToScreenName":"zerohora",
                   "retweetCount":76,
                   "isPossiblySensitive":false,
                   "contributorsIDs":[],
                   "userMentionEntities":[{"name":"Zero Hora",
                                           "screenName":"zerohora",
                                           "id":13531162,
                                           "start":23,
                                           "end":32}],
                    "urlEntities":[{"url":"http://t.co/ho1jjRsIpH",
                                    "expandedURL":"http://zh.com.br",
                                    "displayURL":"zh.com.br",
                                    "start":48,
                                    "end":70}],
                    "hashtagEntities":[],
                    "mediaEntities":[{"id":496694316467646464,
                                      "url":"http://t.co/VPRDdg35oO",
                                      "mediaURL":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/BuSc2WcCcAA49F5.jpg",
                                      "mediaURLHttps":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BuSc2WcCcAA49F5.jpg",
                                      "expandedURL":"http://twitter.com/zerohora/status/496694316656381952/photo/1",
                                      "displayURL":"pic.twitter.com/VPRDdg35oO",
                                      "sizes":{"0":{"width":150,"height":150,"resize":101},"1":{"width":340,"height":375,"resize":100},"2":{"width":477,"height":527,"resize":100},"3":{"width":477,"height":527,"resize":100}},
                                      "type":"photo",
                                      "start":71,
                                      "end":93}],
                    "currentUserRetweetId":-1,
                    "user":{"id":49315012,
                            "name":"Lucas Silveira",
                            "screenName":"lucasfresno",
                            "location":"Em tudo que ? lugar.",
                            "description":"Fresno, Beeshop, SIRsir, Visconde, Vaconaut \u0026 The Apple Monster, Dark Matter, Poop Straps...",
                            "descriptionURLEntities":[],
                            "isContributorsEnabled":false,
                            "profileImageUrl":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000615174403/68c2ac7b73415c6e06d71f8330b50d55_normal.jpeg",
                            "profileImageUrlHttps":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000615174403/68c2ac7b73415c6e06d71f8330b50d55_normal.jpeg",
                            "url":"http://www.fresnorock.com.br",
                            "isProtected":false,
                            "followersCount":883117,
                            "profileBackgroundColor":"FFFFFF",
                            "profileTextColor":"666666",
                            "profileLinkColor":"2FC2EF",
                            "profileSidebarFillColor":"252429",
                            "profileSidebarBorderColor":"181A1E",
                            "profileUseBackgroundImage":true,
                            "showAllInlineMedia":false,
                            "friendsCount":628,
                            "createdAt":"Jun 21, 2009 10:34:03 AM",
                            "favouritesCount":80,
                            "utcOffset":-10800,
                            "timeZone":"Brasilia",
                            "profileBackgroundImageUrl":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/414221729/space.jpg",
                            "profileBackgroundImageUrlHttps":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/414221729/space.jpg",
                            "profileBackgroundTiled":false,
                            "lang":"en",
                            "statusesCount":55070,
                            "isGeoEnabled":true,
                            "isVerified":true,
                            "translator":false,
                            "listedCount":8724,
                            "isFollowRequestSent":false}},
"userMentionEntities":[{"name":"Lucas Silveira",
                        "screenName":"lucasfresno",
                        "id":49315012,
                        "start":3,
                        "end":15},
                       {"name":"Zero Hora",
                        "screenName":"zerohora",
                        "id":13531162,
                        "start":40,
                        "end":49}],
"urlEntities":[{"url":"http://t.co/ho1jjRsIpH",
                "expandedURL":"http://zh.com.br",
                "displayURL":"zh.com.br",
                "start":65,
                "end":87}],
"hashtagEntities":[],
"mediaEntities":[{"id":496694316467646464,
                  "url":"http://t.co/VPRDdg35oO",
                  "mediaURL":"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/BuSc2WcCcAA49F5.jpg",
                  "mediaURLHttps":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BuSc2WcCcAA49F5.jpg",
                  "expandedURL":"http://twitter.com/zerohora/status/496694316656381952/photo/1",
                  "displayURL":"pic.twitter.com/VPRDdg35oO",
                  "sizes":{"0":{"width":150,"height":150,"resize":101},"1":{"width":340,"height":375,"resize":100},"2":{"width":477,"height":527,"resize":100},"3":{"width":477,"height":527,"resize":100}},
                  "type":"photo",
                  "start":88,
                  "end":110}],
"currentUserRetweetId":-1,
"user":{"id":25413124,
        "name":"Mariana Mussi",
        "screenName":"MarianaMussi",
        "location":"Brazil",
        "description":"Minky Momo is here...E sigam-me os bons! Ps: Sou um docinho sim, mas ?s vezes posso ser de maracuj? ou lim?o ;) ? http://about.me/mariana.mussi",
        "descriptionURLEntities":[],
        "isContributorsEnabled":false,
        "profileImageUrl":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3487510187/6545498cd8cd7605637d9458c4c9e272_normal.jpeg",
        "profileImageUrlHttps":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3487510187/6545498cd8cd7605637d9458c4c9e272_normal.jpeg",
        "url":"http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id\u003d1106187557",
        "isProtected":false,
        "followersCount":391,
        "profileBackgroundColor":"FFBDCF",
        "profileTextColor":"41474D",
        "profileLinkColor":"4DABC7",
        "profileSidebarFillColor":"F7FBFC",
        "profileSidebarBorderColor":"FFFFFF",
        "profileUseBackgroundImage":true,
        "showAllInlineMedia":false,
        "friendsCount":386,
        "createdAt":"Mar 19, 2009 8:46:35 PM",
        "favouritesCount":4991,
        "utcOffset":-10800,
        "timeZone":"Brasilia",
        "profileBackgroundImageUrl":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/195172436/minkymomomarianamussibg5.png",
        "profileBackgroundImageUrlHttps":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/195172436/minkymomomarianamussibg5.png",
        "profileBannerImageUrl":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/25413124/1355939835",
        "profileBackgroundTiled":true,
        "lang":"pt",
        "statusesCount":38951,
        "isGeoEnabled":true,
        "isVerified":false,
        "translator":false,
        "listedCount":9,
        "isFollowRequestSent":false}
}
```

And here is the Object result from the Status s = TwitterObjectFactory.createStatus(line); call.

```
StatusJSONImpl{
    createdAt=null, 
    id=496733290263760896,
    text='RT @lucasfresno: Bora se encacha?ar! RT @zerohora: Leia agora em http://t.co/ho1jjRsIpH http://t.co/VPRDdg35oO', 
    source='<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>', 
    isTruncated=false, 
    inReplyToStatusId=-1, 
    inReplyToUserId=-1, 
    isFavorited=false, 
    isRetweeted=false, 
    favoriteCount=-1, 
    inReplyToScreenName='null', 
    geoLocation=null, 
    place=null, 
    retweetCount=-1, 
    isPossiblySensitive=false, 
    lang='null', 
    contributorsIDs=[], 
    retweetedStatus=null, 
    userMentionEntities=[], 
    urlEntities=[], 
    hashtagEntities=[], 
    mediaEntities=[], 
    symbolEntities=[], 
    currentUserRetweetId=-1, 
    user=UserJSONImpl{
        id=25413124, 
        name='Mariana Mussi', 
        screenName='null', 
        location='Brazil', 
        description='Minky Momo is here...E sigam-me os bons! Ps: Sou um docinho sim, mas ?s vezes posso ser de maracuj? ou lim?o ;) ? http://about.me/mariana.mussi', 
        isContributorsEnabled=false, 
        profileImageUrl='null', 
        profileImageUrlHttps='null', 
        isDefaultProfileImage=false, 
        url='http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1106187557', 
        isProtected=false, 
        followersCount=-1, 
        status=null, 
        profileBackgroundColor='null', 
        profileTextColor='null', 
        profileLinkColor='null', 
        profileSidebarFillColor='null', 
        profileSidebarBorderColor='null', 
        profileUseBackgroundImage=false, 
        isDefaultProfile=false, 
        showAllInlineMedia=false, 
        friendsCount=-1, 
        createdAt=null, 
        favouritesCount=-1, 
        utcOffset=-1, 
        timeZone='null', 
        profileBackgroundImageUrl='null', 
        profileBackgroundImageUrlHttps='null', 
        profileBackgroundTiled=false, 
        lang='pt', 
        statusesCount=-1, 
        isGeoEnabled=false, 
        isVerified=false, 
        translator=false, 
        listedCount=-1, 
        isFollowRequestSent=false
        }
}
```

Has anyone ever solved this? I have not found an actual solution anywhere.
Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT: I downloaded the source from GIT and fixed the createStatus method myself locally. Still, it seems that this issue should have been fixed by now, unless there is something I'm missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is, What do you want to accomplish?
It's easier create a JSONObject and then do whatever you want with the Status. Twitter4j has a JSONObject interface, or you could use [org.json](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json), and if you want, for example, the retweetedStatus you only need get that from the Json that you stored.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(line);
System.out.println(json.get("retweeted_status"));
```

**UPDATE**

Your original JSON is wrong, you have `retweetedStatus` instead of `retweeted_status` as the RT field, and that is why you are always getting NULL. A JSON form twitter is like this

```
{
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
  "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
  "coordinates": null,
  "created_at": "Wed Oct 22 18:05:19 +0000 2014",
  "truncated": false,
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
  "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>",
  "retweeted_status": {
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "created_at": "Wed Oct 22 17:58:08 +0000 2014",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "source": "<a href=\"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/twitter/id409789998?mt=12\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Mac</a>",
    "retweet_count": 6,
    "retweeted": false,
    "geo": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "entities": {
      "urls": [],
      "hashtags": [
        {
          "indices": [
            91,
            101
          ],
          "text": "Microsoft"
        },
        {
          "indices": [
            102,
            110
          ],
          "text": "Windows"
        },
        {
          "indices": [
            129,
            140
          ],
          "text": "LeyZamudio"
        }
      ],
      "user_mentions": [
        {
          "indices": [
            46,
            52
          ],
          "screen_name": "Corfo",
          "id_str": "57015564",
          "name": "Corfo",
          "id": 57015564
        }
      ],
      "symbols": []
    },
    "id_str": "524983055652360192",
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "favorite_count": 4,
    "id": 524983055652360200,
    "text": "El Chileno tiene derecho a postular a capital @Corfo Pero q NO te dejen postular x NO usar #Microsoft #Windows es Discriminación #LeyZamudio",
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "lang": "es",
    "user": {
      "utc_offset": null,
      "friends_count": 780,
      "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/492125365293568000/qsIuWYjP_normal.jpeg",
      "listed_count": 34,
      "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme14/bg.gif",
      "default_profile_image": false,
      "favourites_count": 135,
      "description": "Músico & Geek; Marido & Papá. Co-Fundador & Director Ejecutivo de @pantalla_cl; stay hungry, stay foolish (Steve Jobs -June 2005)",
      "created_at": "Tue Mar 11 12:53:02 +0000 2008",
      "is_translator": false,
      "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme14/bg.gif",
      "protected": false,
      "screen_name": "andresreitze",
      "id_str": "14122556",
      "profile_link_color": "009999",
      "is_translation_enabled": false,
      "id": 14122556,
      "geo_enabled": true,
      "profile_background_color": "131516",
      "lang": "es",
      "profile_sidebar_border_color": "EEEEEE",
      "profile_location": null,
      "profile_text_color": "333333",
      "verified": false,
      "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/492125365293568000/qsIuWYjP_normal.jpeg",
      "time_zone": null,
      "url": "http://t.co/IodqmRZoS7",
      "contributors_enabled": false,
      "profile_background_tile": true,
      "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/14122556/1398980661",
      "entities": {
        "description": {
          "urls": []
        },
        "url": {
          "urls": [
            {
              "display_url": "facebook.com/Pantalla.cl",
              "indices": [
                0,
                22
              ],
              "expanded_url": "http://www.facebook.com/Pantalla.cl",
              "url": "http://t.co/IodqmRZoS7"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "statuses_count": 26786,
      "follow_request_sent": false,
      "followers_count": 1269,
      "profile_use_background_image": true,
      "default_profile": false,
      "following": false,
      "name": "Andrés Reitze",
      "location": "Santiago, Chile",
      "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "EFEFEF",
      "notifications": false
    },
    "favorited": false
  },
  "retweet_count": 6,
  "retweeted": false,
  "geo": null,
  "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
  "entities": {
    "urls": [],
    "hashtags": [
      {
        "indices": [
          109,
          119
        ],
        "text": "Microsoft"
      },
      {
        "indices": [
          120,
          128
        ],
        "text": "Windows"
      },
      {
        "indices": [
          139,
          140
        ],
        "text": "LeyZamudio"
      }
    ],
    "user_mentions": [
      {
        "indices": [
          3,
          16
        ],
        "screen_name": "andresreitze",
        "id_str": "14122556",
        "name": "Andrés Reitze",
        "id": 14122556
      },
      {
        "indices": [
          64,
          70
        ],
        "screen_name": "Corfo",
        "id_str": "57015564",
        "name": "Corfo",
        "id": 57015564
      }
    ],
    "symbols": []
  },
  "id_str": "524984861342564352",
  "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
  "favorite_count": 0,
  "id": 524984861342564350,
  "text": "RT @andresreitze: El Chileno tiene derecho a postular a capital @Corfo Pero q NO te dejen postular x NO usar #Microsoft #Windows es Discrim…",
  "place": null,
  "contributors": null,
  "lang": "es",
  "user": {
    "utc_offset": -10800,
    "friends_count": 1419,
    "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/458940469443952641/k4W4RMkF_normal.jpeg",
    "listed_count": 5,
    "profile_background_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/83201515/TWITTER.jpg",
    "default_profile_image": false,
    "favourites_count": 7,
    "description": "",
    "created_at": "Thu Jan 21 20:37:37 +0000 2010",
    "is_translator": false,
    "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/83201515/TWITTER.jpg",
    "protected": false,
    "screen_name": "estebanmmp",
    "id_str": "107197310",
    "profile_link_color": "009999",
    "is_translation_enabled": false,
    "id": 107197310,
    "geo_enabled": true,
    "profile_background_color": "131516",
    "lang": "es",
    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "EEEEEE",
    "profile_location": null,
    "profile_text_color": "333333",
    "verified": false,
    "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/458940469443952641/k4W4RMkF_normal.jpeg",
    "time_zone": "Santiago",
    "url": null,
    "contributors_enabled": false,
    "profile_background_tile": false,
    "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/107197310/1398254745",
    "entities": {
      "description": {
        "urls": []
      }
    },
    "statuses_count": 2354,
    "follow_request_sent": false,
    "followers_count": 390,
    "profile_use_background_image": true,
    "default_profile": false,
    "following": false,
    "name": "ESTEBAN MMP",
    "location": "viña del mar, chile",
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "EFEFEF",
    "notifications": false
  },
  "favorited": false
}
```

How are you storing your data? you need to call `TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status)` to get the raw JSON. Probably you didn't do it in that way and that's why twitterobjectfactory.createstatus returns retweetedStatus always as null.

Comment: The thing is that I have over 50 features I had previously build for a project that used live data and expected a Status object. I transformed them into a library and I wish to use them in this new project.
I agree that the JSON would have the information, but maintaining that code would take more time than fixing the Twitter4J library.

Comment: Your original JSON is wrong, you have retweetedStatus instead of retweeted_status as the RT field ):

Comment: Thanks for the help, FeanDoe! This answers my question.